# Нужно осуществить циклический сдвиг элементов прямоугольной матрицы на n элементов вправо или вниз. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

```
from random import *
import numpy as np

n=int(input("Введите размер матрицы (NxN): "))

p = int(input())
A = 20*np.random.random(size=(n,n)) - 10
for Row in range(n):
    for Col in range(n):
        print("{0:>5.2f}".format(A[Row][Col]), end=" ")
    print()
print()

k = len(A)
print(k)

m = 0

for p in range(n):
    i = k-1
    m = A[i]
    for i in range(k-1,0,-1):
        A[i] = A[i-1]
    A[0] = m
    p -= 1


for Row in range(n):
    for Col in range(n):
        print("{0:>5.2f}".format(A[Row][Col]), end=" ")
    print()
```

Появилось такая проблема, при выводе конечной матрице программа не использует последнию строку. Что то вроде такого:
Введите размер матрицы (NxN):

1.99 -9.13  4.59 -4.08  6.34

-2.82 -6.40  7.16 -3.77  7.03

9.37 -9.88  2.03 -2.13 -2.55

-3.08  3.68  2.51  7.39 -3.01

-2.43 -4.50  8.02  9.93  3.22

Матрица после сдвига

-3.08  3.68  2.51  7.39 -3.01

1.99 -9.13  4.59 -4.08  6.34

-2.82 -6.40  7.16 -3.77  7.03

9.37 -9.88  2.03 -2.13 -2.55

-3.08  3.68  2.51  7.39 -3.01

Помогите пожалуйста исправить.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, видимо, как обычно копируется ссылка на объект, а не сам объект (в данном случае объект - это строка матрицы), кроме того у вас цикл вообще непонятное что-то делает, поэтому как-то так:

```
A[:-1,:],A[-1,:] = A[1:,:],A[0,:].copy()
```

Почему основная матрица нормально копируется и так, а отдельную строку нужно через `copy()` копировать я пока и сам до конца не разобрался что-то.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь встроенной функцией numpy.roll
Пример:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
print(a)
a=np.roll(a, 1, axis=0)
print(a)
```